# Bumpiness of grassy meadow

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, particles

I am doing [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zhYtJ_VmvXE) of Blender Guru on making grass. Around 20:00 min he shows his render:

[image]

When I look at my render the meadow of Blender Guru is more "bumpy". As far as I know I have the same settings in my blend file (attached). Why is there a difference in "bumpiness" ?

[image]

You can download the Blend file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xwj3djpblnfxfo/grassy_meadow.blend?dl=0). For some reason (?) the file is close to 150MB and cannot be uploaded to Blend Exchange

Comment: If you could provide additional info e.g. unit setup, texture mapping, particle setup you can get faster response time from the community.

Comment: @Delagone I uploaded my blend file for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increase the strength of the displace modifiers.

[image]

The [displace modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/deform/displace.html?highlight=displace) works by using the brightness of the texture to displace the vertices of a mesh on a particular axis.In this case the bright areas of the texture will displace upwards while the dark ones will push vertices down.

It is possible that the contrast and brightness settings used on your texture don't exactly match those of the so called "tutorial".

Comment: thanks, now I understand the function of the texture better. So I could also increase the contrast of the texture ? What is the better "method" ? Have an average contrast and work with the strength of the modifier or set higher contrast and be subtle in the strength of the modifier ?

Comment: The strength of the modifier will set the **absolute** limits, where white will be the highest value, black the lowest. Nothing will be higher or lower than that. Changing the contrast on ther texure will make the slopes more or less steep, the brightness will affect the overall displacement value, but will still be limited by the strength of the modifier.